# additional text fields in html form after a numeric entry in another text field

Tags: text, dynamic, field

Am using an html form to send data to a sql database using php.

My trouble is that I have a dynamic value for number of items which changes for each order and am trying to avoid having to add an x number of extra text fields for all orders.

A better solution would be to enter a value in a text field which then makes the same number of additional text fields appear in the form.

Is there anyway to accomplish this?

Thanks

Comment: Do you want to develop a webpage that shows a _different_ number of input fields (at the user's request) for each use?

Comment: Yes, but I would like that to happen without pressing the submit button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK. So you want to show a number of input fields at the user's request, before pressing the `submit` button. My first approach would be to do it *in javascript*.

Let's assume this form:

```
<form>
<p><input name="myInput1" /></p>
<button type="submit">submit</button>
</form>
```

You could include an extra button to add a new row:

```
<form>
<p><input name="myInput1" /></p>
<button type="button" onclick="addInput(this.form)">add input</button>
<button type="submit">submit</button>
</form>
```

... and the handler function would be something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function addInput(form)
{
    // Create a new <p><input> node at the end of the form, throughput the DOM API:

    // Get the last <p> element of the form
    var paragraphs=form.getElementsByTagName("P")
    var lastParagraph=paragraphs[paragraphs.length-1]

    // Create a new <p> element with a <input> child:
    var newParagraph=document.createElement("P")
    var newInput=document.createElement("INPUT")
    // Name the <input> with a numeric suffix not to produce duplicates:
    newInput.name="myInput"+(1+paragraphs.length)
    newParagraph.appendChild(newInput)

    // Add the created <p> after the last existing <p> of the form:
    form.insertBefore(newParagraph, lastParagraph.nextSibling)
}
</script>
```

(Notice that all the rendering logic is performed *in the client side* (in HTML + javascript), and when the form is finally submitted, the server will just receive a collection of pairs name + value.)

Comment: awesome, if you do not mind, could you explain the "var paragraphs=form.getElementsByTagName("P")
    var lastParagraph=paragraphs[paragraphs.length-1]
    var newParagraph=document.createElement("P")" section. thanks

Comment: Of corse. I've added some comments in my answer.

Comment: And, if you are new to the DOM API, I recommend you read the official documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model1